# How to reiterate through all the view in recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve expandable item inside RecyclerView and when one item is expanded the other expanded item must automatically close, can someone please help?

Comment: https://google.com/?q=expandable+recycler+view

Answer (score 2):

**1.** In your adapter, take *two variable* which can hold currentExpandable and previousExpandable positions.

```
   private var previousExpandedPosition = -1
   private var currentExpandedPosition = -1
```

**2.**  *Initialize them where you are expanding your row*. In my case, I am expanding the view on click of that row. Hence, I am assigning it in my ViewHolder.

```
inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        init {
            itemView.myExpandableView.setOnClickListener {
                previousExpandedPosition = currentExpandedPosition
                currentExpandedPosition = adapterPosition

                if (previousExpandedPosition == currentExpandedPosition) {
                    currentExpandedPosition = -1
                }
                notifyItemChanged(previousExpandedPosition)
                notifyItemChanged(currentExpandedPosition)
            }
        }
    }
```

**3.** In your onBindViewHolder method, if the position is currently expanded then view it Expanded otherwise collapse it.

```
if (position == currentExpandedPosition) {
            // showExpandedView
        } else {
            // showCollapsedView
        }
```

Comment: Thansk for your answere

Answer (score 1):

- Use your custom view inside main Recylerview's ViewHolder according to the requirement, use a **flag**(boolean) in your **DataList**(ArrayList) naming "**isColapsed**" which will be **false** initially when you want all the views collapsed.
- **Show** or **Hide** the inner custom view according to the flags state if **isColapsed** is **true** then set the visibility of your inner RecyclerView to **VISIBLE** or if **isCollapsed** is **false** then set the visibility **VISIBLE**.
- Each time you select the view to be expanded then set all other (**isCollapsed**) flags in the **DataList**(ArrayList) to **true** except for the particular position's flag as **false** then most important use **notifyDataSetChanged();** method to update Your UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of notifyDataSetChanged().

keep a boolean to identify an item expanded or not. For example, suppose you are showing a list of students and on clicking a student expand the item and show details of the student.

```
class Student{
String name;
String age;
boolean isexpanded;
}
```

On item click, you set 'isexpanded=true' to the clicked item and 'isexpanded=false' for all other items in the list.

and then call notifyDataSetChanged() to update the RecyclerView. (inside adapter class you have to manage expanding and closing of expanded views by checking the 'isexpanded')

(I am new to Android and I'm not sure this is the best solution or not)

Comment: Thank yor for your answere